# PresetReverb doesn't work at all why?

Tags: android, audiorecord, audiotrack, android-audiorecord, audioeffect

im a testing my audiorecording application for android

im launching an application to be audio recording in real time with audio effects as below

it was applied to equalizer, bass boost, presetreverb API which developer.android provides

in the result, as for equalizer and bass boost effects they seem to work well, but presetreverb effect.. i don't know why because there was no error in Logcat..

presetreverb don't work at all, i'd like to see it though it even work bad..

so im begging you SOF experts' help

**Q: could you find out its cause through my source code?**

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (this.mainSwitch.isChecked()) {
            this.audioForwarder.start();
        }

        this.visualizer.setEnabled(true);
        boolean flag = this.eqSwitch.isChecked();
        ViewGroup localViewGroup = this.eqSettings;

        int i;
        int j;



        PresetReverb localPresetReverb;
        localPresetReverb = this.reverb;

        if (flag)
            i = 0; // .setVisibility(0) -> View.VISIBLE
        else
            i = 8; // .setVisibility(8) -> View.GONE

        localViewGroup.setVisibility(i); // .setVisibility(0) -> View.VISIBLE
        this.equalizer.setEnabled(flag);
        this.bassBoost.setEnabled(this.bassSwitch.isChecked());




        j = this.reverbSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();


        if (j > 0) {
            i = 8;
            for (boolean flag1 = true;; flag1 = false) {
                localPresetReverb.setEnabled(flag1);

                if (this.reverb != null) {
                    this.reverb.setPreset((short) j);
                }
                Log.v("PresetReverb", this.reverb + "effect");
            }
        }
    }
```

im trying on and on expecting your help
any idea appreciated and big helps for me 
:)